# Updating part of a page in Dash python

Tags: python, dashboard

There was a need to send images and display them on a dashboard. The problem is that when sending images, the entire page is updated, not just the image. Because of this, I lose data from the graph and table because they are reset. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Script for sending data:

```
import requests
import base64

with open('frame20.png', 'rb') as image_file:
    image_data = image_file.read()

encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8050/update_image', files={'image': (image_data)})

if response.status_code == 200:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('Nope')
```

Dashboard in which the image is received and displayed on the screen. Reading and displaying images occurs in the functions "def update_image" and "def display_image"

```
import dash
from flask import request
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import urllib.parse
from flask import Flask, send_file
import flask
import io
import xlsxwriter
import random
from collections import deque
import pandas as pd
from dash import dcc, exceptions
from dash import dash_table
import openpyxl
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import base64


# Создаем приложение Dash
server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)
# Создаем начальные данные для графика и таблицы
data = {'Time': [0], 'Y1': [0], 'Y2': [0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
history = {'Time': [], 'Y1': [], 'Y2': []}  # Словарь для хранения истории данных
received_image = None
image_data = None
# Определение макета дашборда
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', style={'width': '50%', 'height': '500px'}, animate=True),
        html.Div([
            dcc.Interval(id='graph-update', interval=1000),
            dcc.Interval(id='table-update', interval=1000),
            dcc.Interval(id='frame-update', interval=1000),
            html.Div([
                html.H4("Данные", style={'margin-left': '-100px'}),  # Устанавливаем отрицательный margin-left
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='live-table',
                    columns=[{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in df.columns],
                    style_table={'width': '100%', 'maxHeight': '300px','margin-left': '100px'},
                    fixed_rows={'headers': True},
                    sort_action='native',
                    row_selectable='multi',
                    row_deletable=True,
                    style_cell={'padding': '5px', 'textAlign': 'center'},
                ),
                html.A(
                    "Скачать данные",
                    id='save-button',
                    style={
                        'text-decoration': 'none',
                        'padding': '10px 20px',
                        'background-color': '#0074D9',
                        'color': 'white',
                        'border-radius': '5px',
                        'cursor': 'pointer',
                        'margin-left': '100px',
                        'margin-top': '60px'  #  margin-top для кнопки
                    }
                ),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='save-dropdown',
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'CSV', 'value': 'csv'},
                        {'label': 'TXT', 'value': 'txt'},
                        {'label': 'Excel', 'value': 'xlsx'}
                    ],
                    value='csv',  # Default value is CSV
                    style={'width': '100px', 'margin-left': '50px', 'margin-top': '25px'}  #  margin-top для Dropdown
                ),
            ], style={'margin-left': '10px'}),  # Добавляем отступ для таблицы
        ], style={'width': '30%', 'height': '100px', 'border': '0px solid black'}),
    ], style={'display': 'flex'}),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='pie-chart', style={'width': '70%', 'height': '500px'}),
        html.Div([

            html.Img(id='image-display', style={'width': '60%', 'margin-left': '180px'}),  # Добавляем margin-left и увелить изобр
            html.H4("Текущее состояние", style={'margin-top': '-400px','margin-left': '-590px','font-family': 'Arial, sans-serif','font-weight': 'normal', 'font-size': '18px'}),
        ], style={'width': '80%', 'display': 'flex', 'align-items': 'center'}),
    ], style={'display': 'flex', 'justify-content': 'space-between'})

])


@server.route('/update_image', methods=['POST'])
def update_image():

    global received_image
    if 'image' in request.files:
        image_data = request.files['image'].read()
        #print(image_data)
        # Декодируйте изображение из формата base64, если оно было передано в таком формате
        try:
            received_image = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')

            # Устанавливаем атрибут src для элемента html.Img, чтобы отобразить изображение


        except Exception as e:
            return 'Ошибка при обработке изображения: {}'.format(str(e))
    else:
        return ''
@app.callback(
    Output('image-display', 'src'),  # Обновляем src элемента html.Img
    Input('frame-update', 'n_intervals'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def display_image(n):
    # Используем переменную с изображением
    global received_image
    if received_image:
        image_uri = f"data:image/png;base64,{received_image}"  # Формируем URI для изображения

        return image_uri  # Возвращаем URI для отображения на странице
    else:
        return dash.no_update
@app.callback(
    Output('pie-chart', 'figure'),
    Input('frame-update', 'n_intervals'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_pie_chart(n):
    labels, values = generate_pie_chart_data()
    fig = px.pie(names=labels, values=values, title='Круговая диаграмма')
    return fig
def generate_pie_chart_data():
    labels = ['Категория 1', 'Категория 2', 'Категория 3', 'Категория 4']
    values = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in labels]
    return labels, values


# Callback для обновления графика
@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'), Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph(n):
    global df, history
    new_time = df['Time'].iloc[-1] + 1
    new_data = {
        'Time': [new_time],
        'Y1': [random.randint(0, 10)],
        'Y2': [random.randint(0, 10)],
    }

    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['Time', 'Y1', 'Y2'])])

    history['Time'].append(new_time)
    history['Y1'].append(new_data['Y1'][0])
    history['Y2'].append(new_data['Y2'][0])

    x_range = [max(new_time - 10, 0), new_time]
    trace1 = go.Scatter(x=history['Time'], y=history['Y1'], mode='lines+markers', name='Тренд 1')
    trace2 = go.Scatter(x=history['Time'], y=history['Y2'], mode='lines+markers', name='Тренд 2')
    layout = go.Layout(title='График', xaxis=dict(title='Время (секунды)', range=x_range), yaxis=dict(title='Y'))
    return {'data': [trace1, trace2], 'layout': layout}

# Callback для обновления таблицы
@app.callback(Output('live-table', 'data'), Input('table-update', 'n_intervals'))
def update_table(n):
    global df
    return df.to_dict('records')

@app.callback(
    Output('save-button', 'href'),
    Input('save-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('save-dropdown', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def save_data_to_file(n_clicks, file_format):
    if n_clicks:
        # Create a file in memory using BytesIO
        buffer = io.BytesIO()

        if file_format == 'csv':
            df.to_csv(buffer, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
            download_name = 'data.csv'
            mimetype = 'text/csv'
        elif file_format == 'txt':
            df.to_csv(buffer, index=False, encoding='utf-8', sep='\t')
            download_name = 'data.txt'
            mimetype = 'text/plain'
        elif file_format == 'xlsx':
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(buffer, engine='xlsxwriter')
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
            writer.close()  # Сохраняем Excel-файл
            download_name = 'data.xlsx'
            mimetype = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'


        buffer.seek(0)

        return '/download-data?format={}'.format(file_format)

# Modify the download_data route to handle different file formats
@server.route('/download-data')
def download_data():
    requested_format = flask.request.args.get('format', 'csv')

    if requested_format == 'csv':
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        df.to_csv(buffer, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
        buffer.seek(0)
        return send_file(buffer, as_attachment=True, download_name='data.csv', mimetype='text/csv')
    elif requested_format == 'txt':
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        df.to_csv(buffer, index=False, encoding='utf-8', sep='\t')
        buffer.seek(0)
        return send_file(buffer, as_attachment=True, download_name='data.txt', mimetype='text/plain')
    elif requested_format == 'xlsx':
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(buffer, engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
        writer.close()
        buffer.seek(0)
        return send_file(buffer, as_attachment=True, download_name='data.xlsx', mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```